# how can I convert charset=us-ascii csv to charset utf-8 in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

like I have  made script

header="SourceFileIdentifier,Document Name,Number of pages,Page
Number,Bank Name,Bank Address,Account Holder Name,Account Number,IBAN
/ BIC,Currency,Statement Number,Statement From Date,Statement To
Date,Handwriting
present,LineID,Date,Value,Reference,Description,Debit,Credit,Balance"

```
while read -r series; do
echo "$header" > "${series}.csv" 
grep "$series" sample.csv >> "${series}.csv"
done < forty.csv
```

this generally saving output in charset us-ascii

I used this  iconv , redo but its not working and i have used this

```
while read -r series; do
echo "$header" | perl -pe 'Encode::encode("utf-8", $_)' > "${series}.csv"
grep "$series" sample.csv | perl -pe 'Encode::encode("utf-8", $_)' >> "${series}.csv"
done < forty.csv
```

but not working still when i do `file -i filename` its shows `charset=us-acsii`
i want all output files in csv charset  utf-8.

Comment: US-ASCII encodes its entire 7-bit character repertoire the same way that UTF-8 encodes the same characters.  Are you perhaps making a distinction with no practical difference?  Or have you considered that the `file` command, which is unavoidably heuristic-based, may just be wrong in this case (on the basis that the file contains UTF-8-encoded characters from outside ASCII's range)?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying actually I want to send data to client in csv utf-8 so when  on windows I manually save file in csv utf 8  and then i check the format on terminal its is showing utf-8 and when i change format of source file in my code with encoding utf -8 my code works but there is no output all files which are saved are blank .

Comment: If you want to force `file` to output "utf-8" you will need to add a Unicode character which is not an ASCII character; but that seems like needlessly complicating things for yourself. Adding an UTF-8 BOM will certainly produce the desired result, but will break the usefulness of the CSV file.

Comment: Just mentioning not every `file` command test is heuristic. From the man page: `There are three sets of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests, magic tests, and language tests`. Text files are probably mostly hueristic-based tested (last set of tests)

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a perfect subset of UTF-8. Every ASCII encoding is also a UTF-8 encoding. `file` is just telling you that this is not just UTF-8, but also that subset which is ASCII.